# Is it possible to use another hosting site for a website but connect to firestore for backend?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I am new to app/web dev and firebase. I am just trying to understand the firestore and want to use it for my app and website. I am aware of firebase hosting, but would I be able to host it somewhere else(ex. Hostgator or some other site) and still connect to the firestore? Or will it only work if I use firebase hosting for my website? Any feedback would be helpful.

I am new to understanding firebase, so I apologize for the really basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You'll just need to use one of Firebase's [Javascript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) options to connect to your firebase storage instance. Simply load these on your website's client or server side depending on your use case, and use the commands found in the linked documentation to interface with Firebase.